# Conditions under which PHP path-traversal with %2e works

Tags: php, directory-traversal

While trying to replicate a security vulnerability on my local machine I realized that PHP on my machine does not decode `%2e` as a dot. I created the following test-file:

```
<?php var_dump(file_exists("%2e%2e/file_that_exists"));
```

Which always returns false. What are the server requirements that an attack like this would work?

I'm running Apache/2.4.18 with PHP 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856693/a-url-resource-that-is-a-dot-2e

Comment: On what system have you seen that script work? To me it looks like it should always fail.